# Search Results Query

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, query

I have search results that I have looking into a specific document library but I only want specific documents to show that are no older than a certain date. I do have a date field as one of the column in the library. I know that this works:

```
Created=1/1/2013..12/31/2013
```

But as many documents were uploaded after the date they were originally created, this query does not help me.

Is there a way to use a custom field that I created within the search query, specifically the date field?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new DateTime column and then populate that with your target date. Run a full crawl and then create a Managed Property from your new column crawled property. Make it queryable at least, refinable and retrievable if you need those features.

Perform another full crawl and then you should be able to perform the same query above just reference your new Managed Property instead.